# Difference between SVM implementations

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, rapidminer

I am trying to implement an SVM in Rapidminer.  However I am presented with several SVM implementations, libsvm, mysvm,JMySVM, Particle Swarm Optimization based SVM and Evolutionary SVM. Know I know the basic differences between the implementations but what are the advantages and disadvantages of them to know which one to implement?

I am not finding much information about this online, I would like to avoid a try them all to see which one presents the best results. So I would like to know in which situation I should use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first, you seem to confuse different implementations and algorithms. As far as I know, libsvm, mysvm and JmySVM are standard implementation which solve the SVM optimization problem by algorithms such as [sequential minimal optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_minimal_optimization).

On the contrary, the other SVMs you mentioned (additionally) use less common approaches like particle swarm optimization or evolutionary algorithms for the optimization. Such methods usually give you good approximation with small effort, which might be advantageous for large-scale problems (--but I admit I don't know the exact motivation for their invention).

If you are looking for the SVM model which is common in machine learning and related fields, I would suggest you to try the library `libsvm`. Alternatively, you can have a look on the collection [here](http://www.support-vector-machines.org/SVM_soft.html).